# Matlab multiple cores

Tags: multithreading, matlab

I'm running an algorithm that's taking a lot of resources, and maxes out the CPU.

The problem is that it's only using one CPU.

How can i make MATLAB multithread the computations and use more than 1 CPU ?

Comment: you need an environment suited to multi core and MATLAB isn't very suited

Comment: I know it IS possible , the documentation does say that it is, but i couldn't find actually HOW to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The settings are at:

**File>Preferences>General>Multithreading** in R2007a or newer

Affected functions are described at:

[Which MATLAB functions benefit from multithreading](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-4PG4AN/?solution=1-4PG4AN)

Answer (score 2):

Unless you specifically use parallel constructs -- that is, using explicit parallelism -- or use built-in functions that have already been parallelized for you -- Matlab will not run faster on a multicore machine. This post has a list of built-in functions that have been parallelized and so will take advantage of multiple cores:

http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=1894

Here's an example of using a parallel construct to roll your own parallelism:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13775

Comment: That's just no true. It will run faster on parallel machines.

Comment: @Yochai - edited to clarify (it runs faster if you use already-parallelized functions, otherwise, not).

Comment: +1 Right, but MATLAB itself parallelisese even basic matrix operations (multiplication, MIN,MAX,INV,SQRT,POW). For matrices that are larger than 40K elements. BUT you did give a nice example on how to parallelize your own functions.